# I uninstall python3.9 and installed python3.8 now it shows error “'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command”

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.8

```
C:\python\Python3.8>python -m pip install pip
```

Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python\python3.8\lib\site-packages (20.3)

```
C:\python\Python3.8>pip --version
```

'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

`python -m pip` is correct usage, and it shows it is already installed.

If you want `pip` available on its own, you need to edit your PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

For me I just installed anaconda and it worked

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: i don't really understand how it worked . i just thought that i could just use conda instead of pip to my amazement after installing conda pip started to work . so i tested by uninstalling conda to see if the problem had been fixed but once again it said pip was not recognized

Answer (score -2):

You can install pip using the method given in [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows) link.

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Hey thanks for solution but when i got to the location and typed it shows another error C:\Users\Hiren\Desktop>python get-pip.py
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Comment: haha you forgot to set the environment variables for python. go to python installation directory and copy the path to system environment variables.